# Symfony preUpdate event in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata

I have Products entity with fields

- name,
- purch_price_net
- purch_price_gross
- purch_vat_value
- purch_vat_rate_id [from other table]

I need feature, that when user editing in `SonataAdminBundle` `purch_price_net` field, `purch_price_gross` [and other fields] automatically change their values.

So I created `PreUpdateProducts` listener:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Products;

    // echo Events::preUpdate;
    class PreUpdateProducts {
        public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs) {
            if ($eventArgs->getEntity () instanceof Products) {
                if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField ( 'purchPriceNet' )) {
                    $newPurchPriceNet = $eventArgs->getNewValue ( 'purchPriceNet' );


                    $eventArgs->setNewValue ( 'purchPriceGross', $newPurchPriceNet * 1.23 );
                    $eventArgs->setNewValue ( 'name', 'changedName' ); // for tests
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and in services.yml added:

```
services:
[...]

    my.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\PreUpdateProducts
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: PreUpdateProducts }
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work, nothing changes [apart purchPriceNet] after pressing 'Update'.
How can I get it to work?

Comment: How do you trigger event `PraUpdateProducts`? Because there's no such event in Symfony/Doctrine. Lifecycle events should be defined in entity's mapping. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: (Probably) off-topic, but using plural in an entity name is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

OK thanks.

I did it in this way:

in Products class added annotation:

```
* @ORM\EntityListeners({"AppBundle\EventListener\PreUpdateProduct"})
```

and my PreUpdateProduct class look like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Products;
class PreUpdateProduct {

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate(Products $product, PreUpdateEventArgs $event) {
        if ($event->getEntity () instanceof Products) {
            if ($event->hasChangedField ( 'purchPriceNet' )) {
                $newPurchPriceNet = $event->getNewValue ( 'purchPriceNet' );
                $purchVatRateObj=$product->getPurchVatRate();
                $purchVatRate=$purchVatRateObj->getVatRate();
                $purchVatValue=$newPurchPriceNet*$purchVatRate;
                $product->setPurchVatValue($purchVatValue);
                $product->setPurchPriceGross ( $newPurchPriceNet +$purchVatValue );
            }
            if ($event->hasChangedField ( 'sellPriceGross' )) {
                $newSellPriceGross = $event->getNewValue ( 'sellPriceGross' );
                $sellVatRateObj=$product->getSellVatRate();
                $sellVatRate=$sellVatRateObj->getVatRate();
                $sellPriceNet=$newSellPriceGross/(1+$sellVatRate);
                $sellVatValue=$newSellPriceGross-$sellPriceNet;
                $product->setSellVatValue($sellVatValue);
                $product->setSellPriceNet ( $sellPriceNet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works.